# How to split OpenMP threads into subteams over a loop

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Suppose I have a the following function which makes use of `#pragma omp parallel` internally.

```
void do_heavy_work(double * input_array);
```

I now want to `do_heavy_work` on many `input_arrays` thus:

```
void do_many_heavy_work(double ** input_arrays, int num_arrays)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_arrays; ++i)
    {
        do_heavy_work(input_arrays[i]);
    }
}
```

Let's say I have `N` hardware threads. The implementation above would cause `num_arrays` invocations of `do_heavy_work` to occur in a serial fashion, each using all `N` threads internally to do whatever parallel thing it wants.

Now assume that when `num_arrays > 1` it is actually more efficient to parallelise over this outer loop than it is to parallelise internally in `do_heavy_work`. I now have the following options.

- Put `#pragma omp parallel for` on the outer loop and set `OMP_NESTED=1`. However, by setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=N` I will end up with a large total number of threads (`N*num_arrays`) to be spawned.
- As above but turn off nested parallelism. This wastes available cores when `num_arrays < N`.

Ideally I want OpenMP to split its team of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` threads into `num_arrays` subteams, and then each `do_heavy_work` can thread over its allocated subteam if given some.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

(For the purpose of this discussion let's assume that `num_arrays` is not necessarily known beforehand, and also that I cannot change the code in `do_heavy_work` itself. The code should work on a number of machines so `N` should be freely specifiable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OMP_NUM_THREADS` can be set to a list, thus specifying the number of threads at each level of nesting. E.g. `OMP_NUM_THREADS=10,4` will tell the OpenMP runtime to execute the outer parallel region with 10 threads and each nested region will execute with 4 threads for a total of up to 40 simultaneously running threads.

Alternatively, you can make your program adaptive with code similar to this one:

```
void do_many_heavy_work(double ** input_arrays, int num_arrays)
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_arrays)
    {
        int nested_team_size = omp_get_max_threads() / num_arrays;
        omp_set_num_threads(nested_team_size);

        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < num_arrays; ++i)
        {
            do_heavy_work(input_arrays[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will not use all available threads if the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is not divisible by `num_arrays`. If having different number of threads per nested region is fine (it could result in some arrays being processed faster than others), come up with an idea of how to distribute the threads and set `nested_team_size` in each thread accordingly. Calling `omp_set_num_threads()` from within a parallel region only affects nested regions started by the calling thread, so you can have different nested team sizes.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that omp_set_num_threads() only affects context of the current thread.